# Is it possible to group records in views when the field to group by is retrieved through different entity relationships?

Tags: views

I'm trying to group records in a view where the value I want to group by is obtained through different intermediary objects and I can only seem to get the grouping to happen through those intermediaries.

Specifically, I have a content type referred to as Request that can be associated with either a request from another of two different content types, Office or Contact. Either of those types can have an association with an Institution. In the report I'm trying to generate, I want to group 'requests' by the related Institution. If I'm dealing with just Contacts or Offices, I can do the group by fine, but combining the two seems eludes me for some reason.

The added wrinkle in this is that a Contact could have an association to an Office as well. So there's a chance records could double up to some extent.

Right now I'm displaying the records in a table format, and returning the Institution name through separate field relations to an office or contact respectively. In the table format I can group by, but I can't necessarily do a group by in a column, it focuses on a field (which there are two different ones, but they return the same value) so I'm a little stumped at the moment.

Not sure I'm explaining this in the best way. At any rate....